# what is the algorithm used to train NN in matlab by default?

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence

I mean when I create a net work with Newff or nntool or any command of matlab is back propagation the default algo???
or we need to write a script if we want to use BP in learning???

Comment: The default might depend on your MATLAB version. Did you [read the manual](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/nnet/nnet_ug.pdf)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTFM. The first line of the function's documentation explains:

> newff Create a feed-forward backpropagation network.
>
> Obsoleted in R2010b NNET 7.0.  Last used in R2010a NNET 6.0.4. The recommended function is feedforwardnet.
>
> ... The training function BTF can be any of the backprop training functions such as trainlm, trainbfg, .... The learning function BLF can be either of the backpropagation learning functions such as learngd or learngdm....